# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError received at instance shutdown

Tags: hazelcast

We are receiving class not found exception during shutdown of our instance. Has any one encountered this error? What can be the solution?

Exception trace is as follow.

```
<Warning> <HTTP> <pl-1> <traffic-1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic
.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1327067796337> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.ericsson.
lifecycle.web.LifecycleListener failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/impl/ClientService$Worker$1.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/impl/ClientService$Worker$1
        at com.hazelcast.impl.ClientService$Worker.stop(ClientService.java:187)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.ClientService.shutdown(ClientService.java:155)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.Node.shutdown(Node.java:372)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.Node.shutdown(Node.java:349)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.shutdown(FactoryImpl.java:320)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.LifecycleServiceImpl.shutdown(LifecycleServiceImpl.java:105)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl.shutdown(FactoryImpl.java:519)
        at com.hazelcast.impl.FactoryImpl$HazelcastInstanceProxy.shutdown(FactoryImpl.java:191)
        at com.ericsson.jee.ngin.ss7.correlation.model.CorrelationLifecycle.stop(CorrelationLifecycle.java:45)
```

Hazelcast version - 2.0.3

Is this a bug? Is there any fix available in later versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no com.hazelcast.impl.ClientService in 2.0 and newer versions.

Probably you have both 1.9 and 2.0 versions in your classpath, that results in problems.